# How to get the post request text without the header

Tags: node.js, express

I am using `app.use( bodyParser.text());` to retrieve the text string from the client. Although I get from `req.body` plenty of additional information along with the string sent from the client, like `content-type` and other http header related stuff. How can I get only the "payload" data sent from the client without the header information?

Here is an example:
I when I print `req.body` i get:

```
------WebKitFormBoundarypOalQplbquvPou2o
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="index1.html"
Content-Type: text/html

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h1>Hello World</h1>

</body>
</html>
------WebKitFormBoundarypOalQplbquvPou2o--
```

What i want is only the html I have sent:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h1>Hello World</h1>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I'm going to guess that what you _actually_ want is a `multipart/form-data` parser like [`multer`](https://github.com/expressjs/multer).

Comment: Do you mean `req.body`, not `app.body`? According `body-parser` doc, `req.body` should be a string: _a new body string containing the parsed data is populated on the request object after the middleware (i.e. req.body). This will be a string of the body_.

Comment: Yeah correct. I edited the question accordingly :)